# How to setup two host configs for Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I am using Devise. I need to push the same rails project to two different heroku apps. Is there a way to setup different hosts for the two apps?

For concreteness, for appA, the production.rb should contain the   `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'appA.heroku.com'}`
 and for appB, the production.rb should contain `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'appB.heroku.com'}`.

However, it seems that it is not possible to have both lines in the same production.rb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use environment variables on your heroku instance to differentiate constants in your rails app.

For example:

```
# production.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['ACTION_MAILER_HOST'] }
```

Then, on your local machine:

```
% cd /path/to/project/A
% heroku config:add ACTION_MAILER_HOST=appA.heroku.com
% cd /path/to/project/B
% heroku config:add ACTION_MAILER_HOST=appB.heroku.com
```

For reference and more examples, see this [heroku article on environment variables](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a config var for this. That way the value is set per heroku deployment and not in the source code.
See the [heroku documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) for more information.